# Yarn add —dev returns root warning

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

When I use yarn add —-dev  I receive the warning “Running this command will add the dependency to the workspace root”

Which makes no sense, since the
—-dev flag is supposed to add it to only workspace

Running yarn add -dev  returns the yarn version.

I’ve tried uninstalling and reinstalling yarn, but the error continues.

I can’t find any info on this problem and I don’t have any idea how to fix it, can someone provide some advice?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `yarn add --dev <package>` is supposed to add `package` as development dependency. To add dependency to a specific workspace, `cd` to that workspace and run `yarn add` there.